# How can i solve _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0" error?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu, tkinter

I am trying to use Tkinter in Python for data visualization. The code here:

```
import fdb
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import sys
import os

if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
    print('no display found. Using :0.0')
    os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')

root = Tk()

def graph():
    plt.hist(total_orders, months)
    plt.show()

root.mainloop()
```

However, i got this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

After that, I researched and found some solutions for this error. I tried some of them:

1- I added `matplotlib.use('Agg')` and doesn't work, I got the same error.

2- I added `if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '': print('no display found. Using :0.0') os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')` it doesn't work either and i got this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"
```

I tried to use xhost but even i installed `sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils` xhost run as `xhost:  unable to open display ""`.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: What, exactly, is the hardware you're trying to run this on?  Does it even have a monitor connected to it?

Comment: I am connected to a server using SSH.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that your DISPLAY variable is not set, it looks like you are running the program without a connected display. If you are connected via SSH, try using the -X or -Y flags.
Example: `ssh -X 10.0.1.59` or `ssh -Y 10.0.1.59`

Comment: How can i use this flags?

Comment: try `ssh -Y [insert ip address]` or `ssh -X [insert ip address]` in the command line for more info. This enables X11 forwarding, which allows graphical content to be forwarded to the client.

Comment: I tried to use flags as you recommended. But I have the same error.  It might be about X11? Should i install it? How can i use it actually?

Comment: try googling "ssh X11 forwarding" and look for tutorials

Comment: `ssh -X ...` does not work if the platform of the client side is Windows unless there is a X server running in client side.

Comment: Consider installing an X-server (such as Xming, Cygwin/X, or X410 for windows, and XQuartz for mac), using a different platform, or running the program at the physical location of the server (with a display connected to the server).